# Custom PyQt MultiSelection Dropdown in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

Been using [his](https://github.com/spanners/pyqt4-examples/blob/master/MultiSelectionExample/MultiCheckComboBox.py) code for my application that I am developing I felt that the behavior is incomplete so I've added some codes to make the behavior fit to what I am developing but the problem is that I can't seem to add the behavior of when I clicked it again it will close not reload.

First I added this line `self.visible=False` in the `ini` function since I don't know how to check whether the the dropdown is open.

Second is I modified line `319` to:

```
if obj == self._lineEdit:
       if self.visible:
            self.visible = False
            self.hidePopup()
        else:
            self.visible = True
            self.showPopup()
```

This works IF you click the dropdown again but when I click outside of the dropdown to close the dropdown it does not open until you click it twice

I also tried to modify some of the events but I quickly found out that when I click to close the dropdown the `QEvent.MouseButtonPress` in line `291` triggers twice.

Current behavior:

- if I clicked the dropdown, dropdown opens
- if I clicked the dropdown again, dropdown closes
- if the dropdown is open and I clicked outside of the dropdown, dropdown closes
- if I clicked the dropdown after closing it by clicking outside, dropdown does not open until second click (My Problem)

How can I make it so that when the dropdown is clicked it will open and close properly even if I clicked outside.

Comment: I have a big question: what behavior do you want to add?

Comment: Tried to clarify it, It takes two clicks of the mouse to open the dropdown, if I close it by clicking outside of the dropdown. What I want it to do is to open again on a single click. regardless of how I close it

Comment: Does that happen with the original code or with your modification? I just tried the original example and I do not see that behavior.

Comment: Yes, it happened after the modification. the original behavior was that the clicking on the dropdown opens it and opens only(the button besides it is excluded). What I aim is just like the behavior of the button

Comment: My question was: what functionality do you want to add to the original code? Maybe this is going the wrong way and we could indicate the correct way, that is called [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), please answer my question.

Comment: I think we are both confused, the original behavior of the dropdown without the modification(what I am seeing) is that clicking on the `QLineEdit` (not the QPushbutton) is that it only opens the `MultiCheckComboBox`, clicking the `QLineEdit` again when it is open only refreshes it. Unlike the `QPushbutton` where it opens and closes it. The functionality that I am trying to add is to make the `QLineEdit` behave like the `QPushButton` when clicked.

Comment: @JuanCarlosAsuncion. I cannot reproduce this. The behaviour of the line-edit and the button is identical in the unmodified code.